# image lightbox with reactjs using jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i am trying to use this image lightbox in reactjs https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_gallery . But it seems to be not working for me in reactjs.I am having problem with onclick function declarations.Here is my code so far:

```
render() {

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }



    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }



    return (
        <div>


            <div className="container">
                <div className="mySlides">
                    <div className="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
                    <img src="img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
                </div>

                <div className="mySlides">
                    <div className="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
                    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
                </div>

                <a className="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
                <a className="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

                <div className="caption-container">
                    <p id="caption"></p>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="column">
                        <img className="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%"
                             onClick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <img className="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%"
                             onClick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>







        </div>

    );
}
```

I have also tried declaring the script into the componentDidMount.But it seems to be not working.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not access DOM in React.
But you should create model of your component in **state**  and map it to **view** in *render()* function

**UPD**:

The code could looks like this

```
const useSlider = (items) => {
    const [pointer, setPointer] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        setPointer(0) // reset pointer if items list changes
    }, [items])

    // Move pointer forvard
    const next = () => setPointer((pointer) =>
        pointer < items.length - 1 ? pointer + 1 : 0
    );

    // Move Pointer back
    const prev = () => setPointer((pointer) =>
        pointer > 0 ? pointer - 1 : items.length - 1
    );

    // Focused item
    const item = useState (() => items[pointer], [items, pointer])

    return {
        pointer,
        next,
        prev,
        setPointer,
        item,
    }
}


const Slider = ({ items }) => {
    const { next, prev, pointer, setPointer, item } = useSlider(items);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="mySlides">
                    <div className="numbertext">{`${pointer + 1} / ${items.length}`}</div>
                    <img src={item.src} style="width:100%" />
                </div>
                <a className="prev" onClick={prev}>❮</a>
                <a className="next" onClick={next}>❯</a>

                <div className="caption-container">
                    <p id="caption">{item.caption}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    {
                        items.map((item, pointer) => (
                            <div key={pointer} className="column">
                                <img
                                    className="demo cursor"
                                    src={item.src}
                                    style="width:100%"
                                    onClick={() => setPointer(pointer)}
                                    alt={item.caption}
                                />
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const items = [{
    src: 'img_woods.jpg',
    caption: 'The Woods'
}, {
    src: 'img_5terre.jpg',
    caption: 'Cinque Terre'
}];
// <Slider items={items}/>
```

Comment: I am getting error on items variable.It says `block scoped variables cannot share name with var`.I am getting data as a json from restapi –